# Increasing/Decreasing values with limited information

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-2010

We have data like below and I am trying to calculate the N/A's by using current information. The N/A's should either be increasing by 15% or decreasing by 15%. Please see the below image for clarity.
Note:
Column grade is a just column "Level + Location + Family" Combined
'Location', 'Family', 'Mid', and 'Level' are the variables.

Before:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/4JTIJ.png

After: (I did not edit the "Before" data, but rather placed them on the side for easier comparison)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QKpDc.png

BEFORE:

```
Grade   Level   Location    Family  Mid
1 - USA Arch    1   USA Arch    N/A
2 - USA Arch    2   USA Arch    N/A
3 - USA Arch    3   USA Arch    N/A
4 - USA Arch    4   USA Arch    50
5 - USA Arch    5   USA Arch    58
6 - USA Arch    6   USA Arch    N/A
7 - USA Arch    7   USA Arch    75
8 - USA Arch    8   USA Arch    88
9 - USA Arch    9   USA Arch    N/A
10 - USA Arch   10  USA Arch    N/A
11 - USA Arch   11  USA Arch    N/A
12 - USA Arch   12  USA Arch    N/A

1 - France Art  1   France  Art     N/A
2 - France Art  2   France  Art     N/A
3 - France Art  3   France  Art     N/A
4 - France Art  4   France  Art     50
5 - France Art  5   France  Art     55
6 - France Art  6   France  Art     N/A
7 - France Art  7   France  Art     N/A
8 - France Art  8   France  Art     N/A
9 - France Art  9   France  Art     N/A
10 - France Art     10  France  Art     N/A
11 - France Art     11  France  Art     N/A
12 - France Art     12  France  Art     N/A
```

AFTER:

```
Grade   Level   Location    Family  Mid Need (Mid column with the needed values)    Notes
1 - USA Arch    1   USA Arch    N/A 30.70625    Decrease by 15% from F3
2 - USA Arch    2   USA Arch    N/A 36.125  Decrease by 15% from F4
3 - USA Arch    3   USA Arch    N/A 42.5    Decrease by 15% from F5
4 - USA Arch    4   USA Arch    50  50  Does not change
5 - USA Arch    5   USA Arch    58  58  Does not change
6 - USA Arch    6   USA Arch    N/A 66.7    Increase 15% from F6
7 - USA Arch    7   USA Arch    75  75  Does not change
8 - USA Arch    8   USA Arch    88  88  Does not change
9 - USA Arch    9   USA Arch    N/A 101.4423625 Increase 15% from F9
10 - USA Arch   10  USA Arch    N/A 116.6587169 Increase 15% from F10
11 - USA Arch   11  USA Arch    N/A 134.1575244 Increase 15% from F11
12 - USA Arch   12  USA Arch    N/A 154.2811531 Increase 15% from F12

1 - France Art  1   France  Art     N/A 30.70625    Decrease by 15% from F16
2 - France Art  2   France  Art     N/A 36.125  Decrease by 15% from F17
3 - France Art  3   France  Art     N/A 42.5    Decrease by 15% from F18
4 - France Art  4   France  Art     50  50  Does not change
5 - France Art  5   France  Art     55  55  Does not change
6 - France Art  6   France  Art     N/A 63.25   Increase 15% from  F19
7 - France Art  7   France  Art     N/A 72.7375 Increase 15% from  F20
8 - France Art  8   France  Art     N/A 83.648125   Increase 15% from  F21
9 - France Art  9   France  Art     N/A 96.19534375 Increase 15% from  F22
10 - France Art     10  France  Art     N/A 110.6246453 Increase 15% from  F23
11 - France Art     11  France  Art     N/A 127.2183421 Increase 15% from  F24
12 - France Art     12  France  Art     N/A 146.3010934 Increase 15% from  F25
```

Sorry for the formatting issue. Not sure how to fix this. It also won't let me post the picture so I included the link below.

I tried a few nested if statements, but wasn't successful.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4JTIJ.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QKpDc.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the `N/A` with nothing then in that column Find & Select, Go To Special..., Blanks:

```
=, Down, *, .85, Ctrl+Enter
```

Then replace the `0`s and repeat with

```
=, Up, *, 1.15, Ctrl+Enter
```

In this order `66.7` becomes `63.75` but reverse the sequence for the latter value - and where groups change and you have a blank row first put something in the relevant cell.

Comment: Hi - thank you for the help. It seems like it doesn't entirely work.

For '9 - USA Arch  9' the values becomes 'USA Arch 16.02885441'. Though it should be 101.4423625.

It seems like it is instead multiplying by the "France" location instead of "USA"